# How i can see all on JScrollPane

Tags: java, graphics, panel, jscrollpane

I did update, paint, repaint graphics but i can't see that all... i was checked viewport but it is limited my View Panel...!
I can't know how can i do... T-T
And i did update that when scrolls are moving

```
    top.add(tf1);
    top.add(new Label("×"));
    top.add(tf2);
    Button set = new Button("SET!!");
    set.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
            try{
                view.remove(board);
            }catch(NullPointerException e111){
            }
            int x=Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText()), y=Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
            board = new Board(x,y);
            view.add(board);
            view.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x*20, y*20));
            view.setBounds(0, 0, x*20, y*20);
        }
    });
    top.add(set);
    rp.add(top);
    editView.setBounds(0, 100, 500, 600);
    editView.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            try{
            //  board.update(board.getGraphics());
            //  board.repaint();
            //  board.paint(board.getGraphics());
            //  board.paintComponents(getGraphics());
                /*view.remove(board);
                view.add(board);*/
            }catch(NullPointerException e2){
            }
        }
    });
    rp.add(editView);
```

'view' is just a Panel(null);
and~ inner class Board = board

```
class Board extends JPanel{
    public Image board;
    public int y,x;
    Board(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        setBounds(0, 0, x*20, y*20);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x*20, y*20));
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setOpaque(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        board = createImage(x*20, y*20);
        Graphics g2 = board.getGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, x*20, y*20);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        for(int i=0;i<y;i++){
            if(i%10==0){
                g2.setColor(Color.red);
            }
            g2.drawLine(0, i*20, x*20, i*20);
            if(i%10==0){
                g2.setColor(Color.black);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            if(i%10==0){
                g2.setColor(Color.red);
            }
            g2.drawLine(i*20, 0, i*20, y*20);
            if(i%10==0){
                g2.setColor(Color.black);
            }
        }
        g.drawImage(board, 0, 0, x*20, y*20, null);
    }
```

i did like this things... i try many ways.. but same i can't fix it... =_=...
please help me!!~~

structure : JScrollPane - Panel - Panel
panel define size method : setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y))

---

i use only graphics when i draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never call `paint` or `paintComponent` methods.

- Just call `repaint` in the method shown by you.
- Make sure you have called `board.setOpaque(true);` at the start.

Good luck.

Comment: hmm... which method on repaint..? just repaint()?? i try it but i can't see fix this problem... and i never use setOpaque method on there =_=...

Comment: call `board.repaint();` in `stateChanged` method, and call `board.setOpaque(true);` in the constructor.

Comment: i try your way but i can see just same view... T-T

Comment: In that case it'd be better if you can post some more code. (Where you tried it)

Comment: 1) Uncomment `board.repaint();`
2) Override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` in `Board` class.
3) Call paint stuff directly on `g` instead of creating image and creating `g2`.
4) Don't catch `NullPointerException`, let it crash (you'd know the error for now).
5) Put `System.out.println("test 1")` etc in listeners and paint method to see if they are actually being called.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that problem How i create a New ScrollPane... =_= 
like this

```
class ComponentScroller extends Container {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4959363258095925908L;
    Scrollbar horizontal, vertical;
    Panel scrollarea = new Panel();
    Component component;
    int orgX, orgY;
    public ComponentScroller() {
        scrollarea.setLayout( null );
        horizontal = new Scrollbar( Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL );
        vertical = new Scrollbar( Scrollbar.VERTICAL );
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        add( "Center", scrollarea );
        add( "South", horizontal );
        add( "East", vertical );
    }
    ComponentScroller( Component comp ) {
        scrollarea.setLayout( null );  // We'll handle the layout
        scrollarea.add( component = comp );
        horizontal = new Scrollbar( Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL );
        horizontal.setMaximum( component.getSize().width);
        horizontal.addAdjustmentListener( new AdjustmentListener() {
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                component.setLocation( orgX = -e.getValue(), orgY ); 
            } 
        } );
        vertical = new Scrollbar( Scrollbar.VERTICAL );
        vertical.setMaximum( component.getSize().height);
        vertical.addAdjustmentListener( new AdjustmentListener() {
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                component.setLocation( orgX, orgY = -e.getValue() ); 
            } 
        } );
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        add( "Center", scrollarea );
        add( "South", horizontal );
        add( "East", vertical );
    }
    public void add_e(Component comp){
        scrollarea.add( component = comp );
        horizontal.setMaximum( component.getSize().width );
        horizontal.addAdjustmentListener( new AdjustmentListener() {
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                component.setLocation( orgX = -e.getValue(), orgY ); 
            }
        } );
        vertical.setMaximum( component.getSize().height);
        vertical.addAdjustmentListener( new AdjustmentListener() {
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                component.setLocation( orgX, orgY = -e.getValue() ); 
            } 
        } );
        doLayout();
    }
    public void doLayout() {
        super.doLayout();
        horizontal.setVisibleAmount( scrollarea.getSize().width );
        vertical.setVisibleAmount( scrollarea.getSize().height );
    }
}
```

I can't find problem on existing source so I create new things look like it... =_=